# Is installing and maintaining / cleaning a septic tank in Spain's Galicia permissionless?

Tags: spain, water, environmental

I have a small [solar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_edificable), 232 m2, and the town hall rejects connecting it to the sewage system because it is not buildable ( *edificable*) due to being smaller than 500 m2. I would like to install a septic tank there so that I can live there in a caravan or a shed. Can it be done in a permissionless way? Is there any law / regulation where I could read about the matter?

Comment: Not an answer to your legal question but no one would use a septic in this day and age - you need an home sewage treatment plant.

Comment: @DaleM - that seems location specific. Septic is quite common in many parts of the US, even for new construction.

Comment: In my part of the world, you need more space for a septic than that, because it's not just a question of finding space for "a tank"; the tank just settles out solids. The remaining water ("effluent") still needs to go somewhere, which takes space *and* needs to be set a distance away from certain things for health reasons.

Comment: The fine for an illegal septic system in Spain per la Ley de Aguas is about 7K, and apparently if you are within 100m of a sewer system you *must* connect to it. If they are refusing to connect you to the sewer, that suggests that you so not have a *solar*, you have a plot of land which you have been denied permission to make into a *solar*. Purportedly, a permit for a septic system is mandatory, you can check https://www.boe.es/buscar/act.php?id=BOE-A-2001-14276